# How to make rounded corner on every tr of table

Tags: css

I am trying make a table in which table every tr will have rounded corner like image below.

[image]

I have tried below CSS code.

```
.newTable {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.newTable td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.newTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.newTable tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.newTable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.newTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.newTable tr:first-child td {
    border-top-style: solid;
}

.newTable tr td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
}
```

But it gave me result like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure you'll be able to accomplish what you need using a table.

Comment: @FunkDoc, You can do it with a `table` no problem. You just can't do it by styling the `tr`

Comment: If you could includ a full working demo with the HTML to actually show the results instead of a drawing of what the results were like - that would be a huge help.  However... I am also not sure that what you want is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in a table the `tr` doesn't like to take styling so you need to add the `border-radius` AND the `background-color` to the row.

Also since you can have N number of table cells we'll use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` to only alter the radius of the first/last `td` in each row.

Spacing out the row can be accomplished by using the `border-spacing` property on the table itself.

**Here's an example that matches your illustration.**

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
td:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Header</th>
   <th>Header</th>
   <th>Header</th>
   <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
   <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe below code can help you:

```css
tr td:first-child span {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;

}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td span {
  border: 1px #666 solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-right: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

tr td:last-child span {
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px #666 solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td><span>1.1</span></td><td><span>1.2</span></td><td><span>1.3</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>1.1</span></td><td><span>1.2</span></td><td><span>1.3</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>1.1</span></td><td><span>1.2</span></td><td><span>1.3</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code -

```css
table {
      width: 100px;
      margin: 10px;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0 10px;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    td:first-child {
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    td:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    }
```

```html
<table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
       <td>Testing</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this way

---

```
    <table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
 table tr {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display: table;
}
table tr td{
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right:none;
  border-left:none;
}
table tr td:first-child{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-right:none;
}
table tr td:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border:1px solid;
  border-left:none;
}
table{
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP question "How to make rounded corner on every tr of table"?